Recycle Custom Runtime Variable with Different Name
I am setting my own variable based on a file extension, the file name is unknown at runtime:
for %%a in (*.drf) do (set "InFile=%%a")
I want to reuse this variable later for a different action. I want to be able to use it like I can with %~n1 which only uses the file name of argument 1. e.g.: MyFile.drf == MyFile. Additionally, %~nx1 will print the (n)ame and e(x)tension of argument (1) (nx1). Per my last note, is there a similar way to construct a custom variable I set like this? I've tried %~nInFile and %%~nInFile with no luck.

No, there isn't. The positional %1 and loop %a/%%a are the only places where cmd supports this type of expansion.
You can do those expansions as part of your for command, e.g. set "InFileName=%%~na", or you can create a subroutine that does set "InFileName=%~1" and call it with call :thing "%InFile%", as possible workarounds.
